# ROS Answers SE migration: service error

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
this is my service client code

> include "ros/ros.h"
> include "scenario/scenario.h"
> include

> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
> ros::init(argc, argv, "remote");
> ros::NodeHandle n;
> ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClientscenario::scenario("stringa");
> ros::Rate loop_rate(0.5);
> while (ros::ok()){
> scenario::scenario srv;
> srv.request.pc="hello word";
> if (client.call(srv)){
> if((unsigned)srv.response.rasp[0]!=255)
> ROS_INFO("%s", srv.response.rasp);
> }
> else
> {
> ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service scenario");
> return 1;
> }
> ros::spinOnce();
> loop_rate.sleep();
> }
> return 0;
> }

but when i launch the program receive ERROR Failed to call service scenario, what is the problem?
P.S i create the service that is called scenario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55010/service-error/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check whether service is getting started correctly using rosservice list command and try calling service from terminal, if it works fine then service is working fine but the way ur calling ur code is not correct.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on 2013-02-12**:
i typed rosservice list
/local/get_loggers
/local/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
/stringa
and then  rosservice type stringa
ERROR: Unable to communicate with service [/stringa], address [rosrpc://nicolo-laptop:40626]

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-12**:
If this is the case then ur service declaration might have some problem. Name of the service is same as package name so try changing name of the service from scenario to something else..it might resolve the problem..